# NodeJS API HTTP POST request with authentication

Tags: php, node.js, xml, api, httprequest

Any idea how to "translate" the following php code sample into an HTTP API request in NodeJS?

```
<?php
$auth='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <Auth>
                <Username>...</Username>
                <PasswordCrypt>...</PasswordCrypt>
                <ShopId>...</ShopId>
                <AuthCode>...</AuthCode>
            </Auth>';
$params='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
            <Params>
                <Key>...</Key>
            </Params>';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.unas.eu/shop/getOrder");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"auth=".$auth."&params=".$params);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo $response;
?>
```

The params has to be sent in (auth, params, XML) POST variables.

Many thx in advance,

Kind Regards,
Zsolt

Answer (score 0):

In **browser** you can easily do request and parse XML using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Or if you just want to parse XML you can use DOMParser():

```
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(txt, "text/xml");
```

With **Node.js** it's a little bit more complicated. Javascript is familiar with JSON (JavaScript Object Notation), so there is no build in XML parser. You must require some kind of XML parser module, e.g.:

1. [libxmljs](https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs)
2. [xml-stream](https://github.com/assistunion/xml-stream)
3. [xmldoc](https://github.com/nfarina/xmldoc)
4. [cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio) – implements a subset of core jQuery for XML (and HTML)

Full example:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch'), //implements Fetch API for making requests
    libxmljs = require("libxmljs"); //xml parser, read about it here: https://github.com/libxmljs/libxmljs

fetch('http://SOME_PAGE.com/data?type=xml')
.then((res) => res.text())
.then((xml) => {
  var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);

  //do something with xmlDoc

});
```